# How can I insert request body into a MySQL database using express js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, postman

So I am trying to make a small api with `MySQL` and `Express JS`, after following a small tutorial online on how to use `MySQL` with `Express` I tried to make this api and send requests with the `postman`, to insert the data I sent using postman I used in my code the `req.body.data` syntax, I tried using tha classic `SQL` syntax of `INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES (val1, val2)` using interpolation for the request body and I also tried the `SET ?` as I saw in the tutorial I watched. When trying to send the request with postman I keep getting the `Cannot read property 'title' of undefined` error. How can I insert data that I send to the table with postman?

**JavaScript**

```
app.get('/addtodo' , (req, res) => {
    let sql = 'INSERT INTO todo SET ?'
    let post = {
        title: req.body.title,
        body : req.body.body,
        date: req.body.date,
        importance: req.body.importance
    }
    db.query(sql, post, (err, res) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log('success');
        console.log(res);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Post method instead get because you can not pass body in get method

```
app.post('/addtodo' , (req, res) => {
    let sql = 'INSERT INTO todo SET ?'
    let post = {
        title: req.body.title,
        body : req.body.body,
        date: req.body.date,
        importance: req.body.importance
    }
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

GET request has no body, it contains only query or params

Answer (score 0):

change `app.get(...)` to `app.post(...)` in javascript code..

**in this case** send `POST` request through postman